# В какой программе можно построить структурную схему операционного автомата

Tags: блок-схема

Нужно построить подобную схему, можете подсказать где её можно построить, в visio 2019 не нашел подобных элементов, в draw.io тоже нет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Подойдёт любой из:

- Dia http://dia-installer.de/
- Inkscape: https://inkscape.org/